# TinyMCE and table borders

Tags: tinymce

In the latest TinyMCE 3.5.8 it seems there's a slight bug with creating a new table.

Clicking the new table button, setting a border, border color, and background color yields this result:

```
<table style="border-color: #39f30b; border-width: 4px; background-color: #f30b22; width: 250px; height: 135px;" border="4"> 
     <tbody> 
         <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
         <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
     </tbody> 
 </table>
```

Right clicking on the table, selecting table proeprties, *not doing anything else* and hitting apply, then changes the markup to this:

```
<table style="border-color: #39f30b; border-width: 4px; background-color: #f30b22; width: 250px; height: 135px; border-style: solid;" border="4"> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

The problem is that the first one is missing the `border-style: solid;`  The initial table, missing the `border-style: solid;` is breaking IE9, and affecting the display in Firefox.

Is there any sort of setting or patch to fix this?

Comment: +1 i do not use tables in tinymce so i cannot give any information for a workaround, but i suggest you file a bug report here: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php